# Is it allowed to ask what's the origin and how a certain stereotype expanded?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Precisely, I'd like to ask about the  stereotype of why asians are considered bad  drivers in, at least, North america.

I guess that, in a broad sense, that could be considered history, but I'm not too sure if this enters in the scope of this site or not.

Would I be allowed to make such a question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have certainly been questions about stereotypes on History:SE before, for example this question about [the origin of American stereotypes of Swedish women](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/38814/24858) or this question on [American stereotypes of Polish people](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/2133/24858).

However, questions would need to be carefully worded such that they comply with the [Stack Exchange Code of Conduct](https://history.stackexchange.com/conduct) and - as always -  the general guidance on [asking questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/asking) in our Help Centre.

Additionally, I would suggest that you limit any such questions in terms of time-period and geography since stereotypes often differ according to time and place.

Even then, there is no guarantee on how our users might respond to such questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow the rules the best I can, I'll post it now.

Answer (score 4):

I know we've had questions like that before. However, in this case, as a longtime American driver myself, I've never heard that one, and thus I think I'd demand evidence that this prejudice is actually A Thing. Examples (preferably from sources talking about the bigotry, rather than those promoting it) should probably be a feature of any such question.

Otherwise, it comes across to me as "Here's a new bit of bigotry that for all you know I made up on the spot that I'd like to use your popular website to help propagate." We've deleted accounts for such activity.

There's also a (admittedly weak) presumption behind even asking any such question that details of bigotry actually have some kind of basis in fact, perhaps even being something the victims did wrong, and aren't just a random fad like bell-bottomed jeans. I find that distasteful, for reasons that ought to be obvious.

Comment: I don't plan on entering on bigotry, it's a stereotype which several people believe, you can see these links who reflect it: https://augustafreepress.com/myth-busting-the-bad-asian-driver-myth-car-insurance-rates-dont-lie/ or https://www.psychologicalscience.org/news/motr/bad-drivers-no-just-bad-stereotypes.html